# Having trouble projecting a ShadowMap on to a surface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, hlsl, cg

So I am having trouble rendering a shadow map in a shader I'm kind of new to shader coding(roughly 3 months), I'll talk you through what I am doing(well what I think I am doing).

So to start off by creating a script(**ShadowCopy.cs**) which copies the shadow map then passes it to a global variable(**_MyShadowMap**). Now the shader(**ShadowMapping.shader**), then I create **getShadowCoord** which calculates the shadowMap then applies the **getCascadeWeights()** to the shadow Coordinates(for Optimal reasons).

Then I create **computeCameraSpacePosFromDepthAndInvProjMat()** which computes the camera space position based from depth and inverse projection matrix. Now the frag function which renders the pixels
making it visible in the Application, but overall its just Screen-Space-Shadows.

So the problem I am facing are the Projection Values which I honestly don't know how to fix. You can see the Problem in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0noAP.png)

The Material Settings for ShadowMapping.shader.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK5sE.png)

**ShadowCopy.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;

public class ShadowCopy : MonoBehaviour
{
public Light m_Light;
RenderTexture m_ShadowmapCopy;
public int TextureSize = 512;

void Start()
{
    RenderTargetIdentifier shadowmap = BuiltinRenderTextureType.CurrentActive;
    m_ShadowmapCopy = new RenderTexture(TextureSize, TextureSize, 16, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
    m_ShadowmapCopy.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
    CommandBuffer cb = new CommandBuffer();

    cb.SetShadowSamplingMode(shadowmap, ShadowSamplingMode.RawDepth);
    cb.Blit(shadowmap, new RenderTargetIdentifier(m_ShadowmapCopy));
    cb.SetGlobalTexture("_MyShadowMap", shadowmap);
    m_Light.AddCommandBuffer(LightEvent.AfterShadowMap, cb);

}
void OnGUI()
{
    if (m_ShadowmapCopy != null)
    {
        GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords(new Rect(0, 20, 150, 150), m_ShadowmapCopy, new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1), false);
    }
}
```

**ShadowMapping.shader**

```
Shader "Custom/ShadowMapping" {
Properties {
_Color("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Albedo (RGBA)", 2D) = "white" {}
}
 SubShader {

  Pass {

        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
      CGPROGRAM


      #pragma vertex vert
      #pragma fragment frag 
      #pragma target 3.0
      #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        #include "AutoLight.cginc"
      uniform float4 _Color;
      uniform sampler2D _MyShadowMap;
      //UNITY_DECLARE_SHADOWMAP(_MyShadowMap);
      uniform sampler2D _MainTex;


        float4 LowResDepth_TexelSize;

        float4 _ShadowMapTexture_TexelSize;
        #define SHADOWMAPSAMPLER_AND_TEXELSIZE_DEFINED
        #define UNITY_USE_CASCADE_BLENDING 0
        #define UNITY_CASCADE_BLEND_DISTANCE 0.1


        struct appdata {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
        #ifdef UNITY_STEREO_INSTANCING_ENABLED
            float3 ray0 : TEXCOORD1;
            float3 ray1 : TEXCOORD2;
        #else
            float3 ray : TEXCOORD1;
        #endif
            UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
        };

        struct v2f {

            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;

            // xy uv / zw screenpos
            float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            // View space ray, for perspective case
            float3 ray : TEXCOORD1;
            // Orthographic view space positions (need xy as well for oblique matrices)
            float3 orthoPosNear : TEXCOORD2;
            float3 orthoPosFar  : TEXCOORD3;
            UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
        };

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
            UNITY_TRANSFER_INSTANCE_ID(v, o);
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);
            float4 clipPos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.pos = clipPos;
            o.uv.xy = v.texcoord;

            o.uv.zw = ComputeNonStereoScreenPos(clipPos);

            clipPos.y *= _ProjectionParams.x;
            float3 orthoPosNear = mul(unity_CameraInvProjection, float4(clipPos.x,clipPos.y,-1,1)).xyz;
            float3 orthoPosFar  = mul(unity_CameraInvProjection, float4(clipPos.x,clipPos.y, 1,1)).xyz;
            orthoPosNear.z *= -1;
            orthoPosFar.z *= -1;
            o.orthoPosNear = orthoPosNear;
            o.orthoPosFar = orthoPosFar;

            return o;
        }

        UNITY_DECLARE_DEPTH_TEXTURE(_CameraDepthTexture);

        inline fixed4 getCascadeWeights(float3 wpos, float z)
        {
            fixed4 zNear = float4( z >= _LightSplitsNear );
            fixed4 zFar = float4( z < _LightSplitsFar );
            fixed4 weights = zNear * zFar;
            return weights;
        }

        inline float4 getShadowCoord( float4 wpos, fixed4 cascadeWeights )
        {
            float3 sc0 = mul (unity_WorldToShadow[0], wpos).xyz;
            float3 sc1 = mul (unity_WorldToShadow[1], wpos).xyz;
            float3 sc2 = mul (unity_WorldToShadow[2], wpos).xyz;
            float3 sc3 = mul (unity_WorldToShadow[3], wpos).xyz;
            float4 shadowMapCoordinate = float4(sc0 * cascadeWeights[0] + sc1 * cascadeWeights[1] + sc2 * cascadeWeights[2] + sc3 * cascadeWeights[3], 1);
        #if defined(UNITY_REVERSED_Z)
            float  noCascadeWeights = 1 - dot(cascadeWeights, float4(1, 1, 1, 1));
            shadowMapCoordinate.z += noCascadeWeights;
        #endif
            return shadowMapCoordinate;
        }


    inline float3 computeCameraSpacePosFromDepthAndInvProjMat(v2f i)
    {
        float zdepth = SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE(_CameraDepthTexture, i.uv.xy);

        #if defined(UNITY_REVERSED_Z)
            zdepth = 1 - zdepth;
        #endif

        float4 clipPos = float4(i.uv.zw, zdepth, 1.0);
        clipPos.xyz = 2.0f * clipPos.xyz - 1.0f;
        float4 camPos = mul(unity_CameraInvProjection, clipPos);
        camPos.xyz /= camPos.w;
        camPos.z *= -1;
        return camPos.xyz;
    }


      half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
      {

            UNITY_SETUP_STEREO_EYE_INDEX_POST_VERTEX(i);
            float3 vpos = computeCameraSpacePosFromDepthAndInvProjMat(i);
            float4 wpos = mul (unity_CameraToWorld, float4(vpos,1));



            fixed4 cascadeWeights = getCascadeWeights (wpos, vpos.z);
            float4 shadowCoord = getShadowCoord(wpos, cascadeWeights);

            float shadow = tex2D(_MyShadowMap, shadowCoord);
            shadow = lerp(_LightShadowData.r, 1.0, shadow);
            fixed4 res = shadow;
            return shadow * tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * _Color;
      }
  ENDCG
  }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few items that jump out at me:

1. Change: 
   `cb.SetGlobalTexture("_MyShadowMap", shadowmap);` to 
   `cb.SetGlobalTexture("_MyShadowMap", m_ShadowmapCopy);`
2. Change: 
   `uniform sampler2D _MyShadowMap;` to 
   `UNITY_DECLARE_SHADOWMAP(_MyShadowMap);`
3. Change 
   `float shadow = tex2D(_MyShadowMap, shadowCoord);` to 
   `float shadow = UNITY_SAMPLE_SHADOW(_MyShadowMap, shadowCoord);`